# Java hashCode(): Override faster that native implementation?

Tags: java, performance, jmh

I am bit surprised that the default (native) implementation of the `hashCode()` method appears **~50x slower** than a simple override of the method for the following benchmark.

Consider a basic `Book` class that does not override `hashCode()`:

```
public class Book {
private int id;
private String title;
private String author;
private Double price;

public Book(int id, String title, String author, Double price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Consider, alternatively, an otherwise identical `Book` class, `BookWithHash`, that overrides the `hashCode()` method using the default implementation from Intellij:

```
public class BookWithHash {
private int id;
private String title;
private String author;
private Double price;


public BookWithHash(int id, String title, String author, Double price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    final BookWithHash that = (BookWithHash) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
    if (author != null ? !author.equals(that.author) : that.author != null) return false;
    return price != null ? price.equals(that.price) : that.price == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (author != null ? author.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (price != null ? price.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

Then, the results of the following JMH benchmark suggests to me that the **default hashCode() method from the `Object` class is almost 50x slower** than the (seemingly more complex) implementation of `hashCode()` in the `BookWithHash` class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(Main.class.getSimpleName()).forks(1).build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public long bookWithHashKey() {
    long sum = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
        sum += (new BookWithHash(i, "Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Bronte", 14.99)).hashCode();
    }
    return sum;
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public long bookKey() {
    long sum = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
        sum += (new Book(i, "Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Bronte", 14.99)).hashCode();
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Indeed, the summarized results suggest that calling `hashCode()` on the `BookWithHash` class is an order of magnitude faster than calling `hashCode()` on the `Book` class (see below for full JMH output):
[image: Summarized JMH]

The reason I am surprised by this is that I understand the default `Object.hashCode()` implementation to (usually) be a hash of the initial memory address for the object, which (for the memory lookup at least) I would expect to be exceedingly fast at the microarchitecure level.  These results seem to suggest to me that the **hashing of the memory location** is the bottleneck in `Object.hashCode()`, when compared to the simple override as given above.  I would appreciate others' insights into my understanding and what could be causing this surprising behavior.

---

Full JMH output:

[image: Full JMH output]

Comment: You should actually do something with the hashcodes (like summing them up) so the whole loop isn't just optimized out due to not modifying any data.

Comment: @Aplet123 good idea, I updated the benchmark as suggested (summing the hash codes).  Results do differ from before but still 50x difference.

Comment: I don't have JMH but I did a simple repetitive test and got similar results as you.  But by simply putting in `public int hashCode() { return 0;}` in the nohash version, they both took about the same amount of time.

Comment: I got about the same results as @WJS , however on scale of 1 bilion repetitions the native hash actually always outperformed overriden hash by about 0.5s.

Comment: FWIW the default hashCode impl uses a thread local variation of Marsaglia's xor-shift to compute the value (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#L838), and then stores it in the object header. In the best case the cached value can be loaded from the object header, but since you're creating new objects every time, I think you're hitting the slow path each time, which is an out-of-line native call (i.e. relatively slow, since none of that can be optimized).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misused JMH, so the benchmark scores do not have much sense.

1. It's usually not needed to run something in a loop inside a benchmark. JMH runs a benchmark loop itself in a way that prevents JIT compiler overoptimizing the code being measured.
2. Results and side effects of the code being measured need to be consumed, either by calling `Blackhole.consume` or by returning the result from a method.
3. The parameters of the code are typically read from `@State` variables in order to avoid constant folding and constant propagation.

In your case, `BookWithHash` objects are transient: JIT realizes the objects do not escape, and eliminates allocation altogether. Furthermore, since some of the object fields are constant, JIT can simplify `hashCode` computation by using constants instead of reading the object fields.

On the contrary, the default `hashCode` relies on the object *identity*. That's why the allocation of `Book` cannot be eliminated. So, your benchmark is actually comparing the allocation of 20000 objects (mind the `Double` object) with some arithmetic operations on the local variables and constants. No surprise, the latter is much faster.

Another thing to take into account is that the first call of identity `hashCode` is much slower than the subsequent calls, because the hashCode needs to be first generated and put into the object header. This in turn requires a call to VM runtime.
The second and the subsequent calls of `hashCode` will just get the cached value from the object header, and this indeed will be much faster.

Here is a corrected benchmark that compares 4 cases:

- getting (generating) an identity hashCode of a new object;
- getting an identity hashCode of an existing object;
- computing an overridden hashCode of a newly created object;
- computing an overridden hashCode of an existing object.

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class HashCode {

    int id = 123;
    String title = "Jane Eyre";
    String author = "Charlotte Bronte";
    Double price = 14.99;

    Book book = new Book(id, title, author, price);
    BookWithHash bookWithHash = new BookWithHash(id, title, author, price);

    @Benchmark
    public int book() {
        return book.hashCode();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int bookWithHash() {
        return bookWithHash.hashCode();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int newBook() {
        return (book = new Book(id, title, author, price)).hashCode();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int newBookWithHash() {
        return (bookWithHash = new BookWithHash(id, title, author, price)).hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
HashCode.book             avgt    5   2,907 ± 0,032  ns/op
HashCode.bookWithHash     avgt    5   5,052 ± 0,119  ns/op
HashCode.newBook          avgt    5  74,280 ± 5,384  ns/op
HashCode.newBookWithHash  avgt    5  14,401 ± 0,041  ns/op
```

The results show that getting an identity hashCode of an existing object is notably faster than computing hashCode over the object fields (2.9 vs. 5 ns). However, generating a new identity hashCode is a really slow operation, even comparing to an object allocation.

Comment: So is it slow because it needs to be put into the object header i.e. putting something into the object header is a slow operation? Or is the generation slow?

Comment: @Oleg Because the code to do it is not inlined into the compiled method, but is always performed through a call to VM runtime function.

Answer (score 2):

The performance difference is due to the fact that you are creating a new object for each `hashCode()` invocation in the benchmark, and the default `hashCode()` implementation caches its value in the object header, while the custom one obliviously does not. Writing to the object header takes a lot of time, since it involves a native call.

Repeated invocations of the default `hashCode()`  implementation perform a little better than the custom one.

If you set `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking`, you will see that the performance difference decreases. Since biased locking information is stored in object headers too, and disabling it affects object layout, this is an additional proof.

Comment: @Oleg "Writing to the object header takes a lot of time, since it involves a native call." I would expect a native call to be the fastest of all calls, no?

Comment: @bcf No because it has to cross the JVM boundary.